# How to consume ASP Rest web Api in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin.forms

I have created a REST Api in ASP.Net web form. I can read and write data from MySql database using the API (I tested the Api using chrome's REST Client extension). Now I am trying to consume the Rest Api in my cross platform xamarin forms. I just added a button in my app and see whether it can retrieve data if I click the button. I inserted a breakpoint at the var Json to see whether I'm getting any data. But I am not able to retrieve it. I am running the Web Api in localhost. I run the app in VS Android emulator. Please guide me on how to properly consume the REST web service. Thank you.

Web Api

```
namespace WorkAppApi.Controllers
{
public class MachinesController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Machines
    public List<machines> Get()
    {
        DBConn db = new DBConn();
        return db.getMachineList();
    }



    // GET: api/Machines/5
    public machines Get(long id)
    {
        DBConn db = new DBConn();
        machines m = db.getMachine(id);
        return m;
    }

    // POST: api/Machines
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]machines value)
    {
        DBConn db = new DBConn();
        long id;

        id = db.addMachine(value);
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, String.Format("machines/{0}", id));
        return response;
    }

    // PUT: api/Machines/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE: api/Machines/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
}
```

Function submit button.

```
namespace WorkApp
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
{
    private string Uri = "http://192.168.0.124:59547/api/Machines/";

    public TestPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        check();
    }


    private async Task submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var json = await httpClient.GetAsync(Uri);

    }



}
}
```

Comment: There are tons of answers in SO about this. Please do some searching.

Comment: I have done the searching. I just need a simple example on how to properly consume the API I created.

Comment: Also, people answering your questions but you have not accepted any of them. Do you think people will continue answering?

Comment: I agree on @Yuri S here, if you don't answer / upvote / accept as answer, the people that would like to help, won't help you anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this would be my answer:

```
namespace WorkApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
    {
        private string Uri = "http://192.168.0.124:59547/api/";
        List<Machine> machines;
        public TestPage ()
        {
          InitializeComponent ();
          check();
        }


        private async Task submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           var httpClient = new HttpClient();
           httpClient.BaseAddress = Uri // I have changed the Uri variabele, you should extend this class and give it the same base address in the constructor.
           var resp= await httpClient.GetAsync("Machines");
            if (resp.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var repStr = resp.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                machines= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Machine>>(repStr.Result.ToString());
            }
        }
     }
}
```