# display a list while clicking in imagebutton and consuming webservice xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, menu, imagebutton

I want to display a list when i click in imagebutton, how can i do to consume a resful webservice while using DisplayActionSheet.
this is the code in xaml:

```
                    <ImageButton Source="list.png" x:Name="listEntité" 
                      Clicked="listEntité_Clicked"/>
```

and in xaml.cs :

```
  private async void listEntité_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     await DisplayActionSheet("entity", "ok");
    }
```

Comment: DisplayActionSheet - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups#guide-users-through-tasks

Comment: thank you; i have updated my publication , can you see it please ?

Comment: Do you have a question about using it?  Or are you getting an error or exception?  I'm not clear what sort of feedback you expect?

Comment: Consuming rest API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest
and then display result in listview or collection view on imagebutton click

Comment: the question you originally posted had nothing to do with RESTful services - you just wanted to display a menu.  Please do not make edits that completely change the topic of your post.  And there are hundreds of existing questions and posts on consuming RESTful services.  Please try to read some of them and solve this yourself before posting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to consume ASP Rest web Api in Xamarin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916935/how-to-consume-asp-rest-web-api-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: my question is how to show a list with DisplayActionSheet,consuming a webservice,  when i click to an imageButton !

Answer (score 0):

When you set the buttons for DisplayActionSheet, you could switch to do something for webservice when the Button is pressed.

```
private async void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        var action = await DisplayActionSheet("ActionSheet: Send to?", "Cancel", null, "Email", "Twitter", "Facebook");
        switch (action)
        {
            case "Email":

                // Do Something when 'Email' Button is pressed

                break;

            case "Twitter":

                // Do Something when 'Twitter' Button is pressed

                break;
            case "Facebook":

                // Do Something when 'Facebook' Button is pressed

                break;              
        }
    }
```

DisplayActionSheet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.displayactionsheet?view=xamarin-forms